# Is it possible for an input element to have a cursor without focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, television

Okay so this is a unique scenario.

This is a web app that is not accessed anywhere but on a set top box. The peripheral for this application is a TV **remote control**.

i.e: **NO keyboard**, **NO mouse**.

Of course normally, when an input element is focused, a cursor appears and blinks at the current position. You type characters, they show up, and the cursor **automagically** advances. whoohoo!

But what we need to do is replicate that behavior **when the input element is not focused**.

This behavior is seen mostly in video games and other TV/large screen interfaces. You have an onscreen keyboard and you choose characters by navigating to a letter or number and hitting enter/select or whatever button is "select" for that platform (like maybe the 'X' button on a Playstation). The letter shows up in the input field, the `cursor` advances, but the actual element with focus is the current key on the onscreen keyboard.

We tried making the keyboard using `<div>` tags, but then we lose the behavior of the very convenient `placeholder` attr, and it is just a mess of logic recreating what a `cursor` and `placeholder` should do. I would love for the `cursor` to ALWAYS be on an input element, just after the last character, and NOT present when the input has no value, showing only `placeholder="Search"`. Almost sounds like I need to be able to have two elements on a page with focus, which is not possible as far as I know.

But is it possible to have an input element not focused and still see a cursor? Or are we stuck using other tags and recreating that behavior from scratch?

Scouring the internet, I have found no solution. jQuery solutions are acceptable.

Comment: If you go to Google.com, and hit the little keyboard icon on the right side in the seach field, is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: What platform? I see a microphone...

Comment: Preferably using something with a keyboard ?

Comment: Have you thought about going the opposite direction: keeping the real focus on the input and faking the focus on the keyboard keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question right but you could simulate a cursor with the `|` character. I put together a quick example that may help you.

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udw2guL0/)

html

```
<input id="cursor" type="text">
```

js

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  input=$("#cursor")

  if(!input.is(":focus") && (input.val()=='' || input.val()=='|')){
      if(input.val()==''){input.val("|");}
      else if(input.val()=='|'){input.val("");}

  }
  else{}
}, 500);
```

Comment: you know, that doesn't sound like a bad idea... clever sir... clever :)

Comment: unfortunately, this will also clear the value of the input itself, just to note